# Converting a pivot table to flat table in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, pivot-table

Consider the following table:

[image]

I am using the query below (in **SQL Server**) to convert this table to a flat table as follows:
[image]

I would like to the same thing using Oracle SQL. However the query does not work in "Oracle SQL" language: `cross apply`, which is used below, does not work in Oracle. Any idea how to write this equivalently using Oracle SQL? Thanks!

```
select t.employee_id,
   t.employee_name,
   c.data,
   c.old,
   c.new
 from test_table t
 cross apply
 (
   select 'Address', Address_Old, Address_new union all
   select 'Income', cast(income_old as varchar(15)), cast(income_new as varchar(15))
 ) c (data, old, new)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of SQL Server APPLY in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476191/what-is-the-equivalent-of-sql-server-apply-in-oracle)

Comment: I don't see it as a duplicate question - this is a specific case whereas the original question was very generic and the answer does not apply at all in this instance

Comment: Not a duplicate at all. Here I am looking for the use of `apply` in the context of a pivot table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite as succinct without the ability to do CROSS APPLY:

```
select t.employee_id,
t.employee_name,
c.data,
DECODE (c.data, 'Address', t.address_old, 'Income', t.income_old) AS old,
DECODE (c.data, 'Address', t.address_new, 'Income', t.income_new) AS new
from test_table t
cross join
(
  select 'Address' AS data
  from dual
  union all
  select 'Income'
  from dual
 ) c
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Does this result in the flat table showed above?