# ORA-00904: invalid identifier in nested subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose, we have query like this:

```
SELECT 
tt.id first_column,
tt.value second_column,
--another values
qq.code_1 third_column,
qq.code_2 column4,
qq.code_3 column5,
qq.code_4 column6,
qq.code_5 column7

FROM
test_tbl tt LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id, code_value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY code_value) AS RN
  FROM attributes attr WHERE attr.id = tt.id AND 
      attr.code IN ('ATTRIBUTE_CODE_1',
                    'ATTRIBUTE_CODE_2',
                    'ATTRIBUTE_CODE_3',
                    'ATTRIBUTE_CODE_4',
                    'ATTRIBUTE_CODE_5')
)
PIVOT (MAX(code_value) FOR (RN) IN (1 as code_1, 2 as code_2, 3 as code_3, 4 as code_4, 5 as code_5))) qq
ON tt.id = qq.id
-- LEFT JOINS with another tables...
```

The problem is error:

```
ORA-00904: "TT"."ID": invalid identifier
```

How can I circumvent this obstacle?

Of course above example is easy and dummy, real query is more complicated.

This example can be checked here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eec83/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the problematic condition:

```
WHERE attr.id = tt.id
```

... but to ensure correct `RN` values, you'll also need to add a `partition by id` inside your `row_number() over` clause.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY code_value) AS RN
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eec83/45):

```
SELECT 
tt.id first_column,
tt.value second_column,
--another values
qq.code_1 third_column,
qq.code_2 column4,
qq.code_3 column5,
qq.code_4 column6,
qq.code_5 column7

FROM
test_tbl tt LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id, code_value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by id ORDER BY code_value) AS RN
  FROM attributes attr WHERE
      attr.code IN ('ATTRIBUTE_CODE_1',
                    'ATTRIBUTE_CODE_2',
                    'ATTRIBUTE_CODE_3',
                    'ATTRIBUTE_CODE_4',
                    'ATTRIBUTE_CODE_5')
)
PIVOT (MAX(code_value) FOR (RN) IN (1 as code_1, 2 as code_2, 3 as code_3, 4 as code_4, 5 as code_5))) qq
ON tt.id = qq.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer the other tables/views in an **inline view**. I couldn't find a documentation which states this, but that's just it. It's by design, how query optimizer treat the query.

The actual case is more obvious with this simple query:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  test_tbl tt , 
  ( 
    SELECT ID, CODE_VALUE
    FROM attributes attr 
    WHERE attr.id = tt.id
    ) qq
```

Error:

```
ORA-00904: "TT"."ID": invalid identifier
```

If you want to do join then you should use `JOIN` and put the condition in ON clause or put the condition in WHERE clause to join inline view and the table.
Like here:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  test_tbl tt , 
  ( 
    SELECT ID, CODE_VALUE
    FROM attributes attr 
    ) qq 
WHERE attr.id = tt.id
```

or see if you want to make a `CROSS APPLY`. It seems like this is a join.

Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20127137/1538014), there is a nice expression:

> An inline view / derived table creates a temporary unnamed view at the beginning of your query and then treats it like another table until the operation is complete. Because the compiler needs to create a temporary view when it sees on of these subqueries on the FROM line, those subqueries must be entirely self-contained with no references outside the subquery.

I believe that's not always true, in some cases oracle can choose to merge inline view. And can be forced to be merged by use of [NO_MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10752/hintsref.htm#26161) optimizer hint.

[SEE THIS](https://community.oracle.com/message/9860690#9860690)

[SEE THIS](https://community.oracle.com/thread/342118)

I intend to add query plan as soon as I can, which may give more idea

Answer (score 0):

You can remove that condition from the inner sub query, because it does not any significance as you already have left outer join on both table on its common column `id`.

You can make below changes to your query.

```
SELECT 
tt.id first_column,
tt.value second_column,
qq.code_1 third_column,
qq.code_2 column4,
qq.code_3 column5,
qq.code_4 column6,
qq.code_5 column7
FROM
test_tbl tt LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id, code_value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY code_value) AS RN
  FROM attributes attr WHERE 
     attr.code IN ('ATTRIBUTE_CODE_1',
                'ATTRIBUTE_CODE_2',
                'ATTRIBUTE_CODE_3',
                'ATTRIBUTE_CODE_4',
                'ATTRIBUTE_CODE_5')
)
PIVOT (MAX(code_value) FOR (RN) 
IN (1 as code_1, 2 as code_2, 3 as code_3, 4 as code_4, 5 as code_5))) qq
ON tt.id = qq.id;
```

Here is the your [Updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/efcae/3)

May this will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, for other data that is not effective. Look at this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac236d/2

Comment: Can you please post sample output?