# Oracle subquery on outter query data

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write something like this.

```
SELECT x,
,y
,(Select z from innerTable where innerTable.this = outterTable.that
FROM outterTable
where blahblah
```

Basically, this particular column I'd like to map to a value in another table. But when I try this, SQLDeveloper just prints out my Select statement as a column heading with nulls below it.

Comment: Why not use a join?

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and needed result? The naming of your tables is quite confusing: why do you query the "outer" table if it is "outer"?

Comment: I didn't want to use a join because this mapping is only applicable to the one column. It seemed cleaner to do it as a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the column an alias to fix the heading:

```
select x, y,
       (Select z from innerTable where innerTable.this = outterTable.that
       ) as z
from outterTable
where blahblah;
```

However, the `NULL` values are because there are no matches, so that is a different issue.

Comment: How would this behave if more than one value is in the z table?

Comment: @JohnHC . . . The OP states that the query runs.  In that case, it would return an error, but that doesn't appear to be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the alias comment. When I do this select subquery on its own though (with a hard value in place of the outter table value) it works. And the values do seem to match in each table. So that's why I was thinking it must be an issue with my subquery syntax

Answer (score 0):

[SQL - Relationship between a SubQuery and an Outer Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106632/sql-relationship-between-a-subquery-and-an-outer-table)

I think this covers it pretty clearly. What I'm trying to do would run very slowly, since it would calculate for each line in the resultset, so it is best that I find another way to do it.