# Oracle pl sql equivalent SQL Server apply statement

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, cross-apply

Does anyone knows a equivalent in ORACLE PL/SQL for the SQL Server `CROSS APPLY` statement? If so what I want is, in a aggregation sub-query alias as a table, just do the aggregation for those IDs and don't do the aggregation for the whole table, before pick up the values that I need.

Quick example:

```
SELECT A.Val1, B.Val2
FROM TABLE1 A
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT SUM(Val2) AS Val2 FROM Table2 T2 WHERE T2.FK1 = A.PK1) B
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476191/what-is-the-equivalent-of-sql-server-apply-in-oracle

Comment: It should work with **exactly** that syntax in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not aware of Oracle syntax, you can rewrite your query so that it should be compatible with both:

```sql
SELECT A.Val1, B.Val2
FROM TABLE1 A
  left join (
    SELECT t2.FK1, SUM(Val2) AS Val2 FROM Table2 T2 group by T2.FK1
) B on b.FK1 = A.PK1;
```

This should actually be more efficient in SQL Server, too, as `apply` tends to be more expensive than `join`, and should only be used when no other alternatives exist.

Comment: But, that will calculate all the aggregation for the whole Table2, and then discard which of them enters to the join. That is the what I was trying to avoid..  
I have a query that works, however, I was trying to enhance the performance. For 0.8 M records it takes some time.. 
Thanks for your answer! 

Comment: I don't know about SQL Server, but in Oracle the "cross apply" operator will definitely work faster than a standard join. The OP knows what he is talking about.